# proving that dual space of $l^\infty$ contains $l^1$ not equal

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, dual-spaces

Each $y \in l^1$ defines a bounded linear functional $g_y : l^\infty \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $g_y(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_ny_n$. Let $c$ be the subspace of $l^\infty$ consisting of all convergent sequences, and $f$ be the linear functional on $c$ given by $f(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty} x_n$. Let $g: l^\infty \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded linear functional extending $f$.

Prove that there is no $y \in l^1$ such that $g = g_y$.

So I think of like, let $y=\{y_k\}_{k\ge 1}\in l^1$, and $c \ni e=\{e_k^{(n)}\}_{k\ge 1}$.  Fix $k\in \mathbb{N}$, and let $y_k = g(e_k) = f(e_k) = \lim_{n\to \infty} e_k^{(n)}$
we have to show that there exists no $k$ , s.t. $y_k \subset y \in l^1$.

Is above correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is given is $\sum x_ny_n=\lim x_n$ whenever the limit exists. 
Put $x=(0,0,...,1,0,0....)$ with $1$ in position $i$ to see that $y_i=0$. This is true for every $i$. Now put $x=(1,1,1,...)$ o get $\sum y_i=1$. we  now have the contradiction $1=\sum y_i=\sum 0=0$.

Comment: Basically the idea is that you supposed that $g=g_y$ , for some $y\in l^1$. Then for any $x\in l^\infty$ there should be a one-to-one correspondence between the $l^1$ and the dual space $l^\infty$. So no matter what $x\in l^\infty$ you take (where here two different was taken) it should be that they must coincide to the same $y\in l^1$. (That we got contradiction to this) right?

Comment: @stat_yale Yes, that is right.